# Review asks me to demonstrate "what is the new thing done"; what should I write?

Tags: publications, writing, peer-review

The referee has asked to demonstrate ' what is the new thing done" so that the paper will be accepted. I feel, though the fundamental theory is same for the work, the experiment at various machine is carried out and result is being published. So what should i write to the journal for convincing the matter.

Comment: Are you sure that the referee is not asking you to demonstrate what is new in your work with respect to the existing literature?

Comment: According to the description, I would suggest that you can say your contribution is conducting several new experiments. This is seemingly just the new thing.

Comment: I have a really hard time parsing this question ("the experiment at various machine is carried out and result is being published.").

Comment: If you feel the need to ask this question of strangers on the internet, you should probably withdraw your paper.

Answer (score 3):

First, it is important to clearly arrive at a conclusion that shows how the manuscript contributes to our unerstanding of the matter at hand. The referee apparently thinks your paper is lacking in this respect.

Second, in most journals it is not up to the referee to decide if a papepr is published or not, the editor(s) decide based upon *recommendations* from the referees (usually more than one). So is there a second referee? and if so what did that person say?

You should revise your manuscript and think about the conclusions. Make them clearer *as suggested* if you think you can. Such comments froma referee usually mean that the manuscript is not as clear as you may think and it is necessary to critically view your work and see if you can improve it. If you cannot, you should provide a note to the editor to meet the criticism of the referee which should entail why the improvements cannot be made. That would make a decision on the faith of the manuscript easier and more clear to the editor (which I suspect is involved).